# Unwanted stripes in ggplot2 bar chart when knitted to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

When knitting a simple bar chart to pdf, I get some unwanted stripes in my bars (see right side of the attached screenshot).

[image]

````
---
title: "Don't Panic"
author: "Ford Perfect"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r, include = F}
library(ggplot2)
```

# Introduction

```{r, echo = F, fig.cap = "My plot"}
ggplot(mpg) + geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hwy), stat="identity")
```
````

These stripes do not appear when I create the plot directly in R-Studio (see left side of the attached screenshot).

I found a way to remove these stripes by aggregating the data before:

```
ggplot(aggregate(hwy~cyl,mpg,"sum")) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hwy), stat="identity")
```

So I understand that these stripes should be coming from stacking all the other groups in the datasets. This theory seems plausible, since I get two stripes when I aggregate the dataset also by years (2 uniques in mpg dataset).

```
ggplot(aggregate(hwy~cyl*year,mpg,"sum")) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hwy), stat="identity")
```

But I thought that ggplot2 is automatically doing the aggregation for me when I set *stat* to *identity*? Actually it does work directly in R-Studio. So maybe the problem has more to do with knitr?

I do believe that I did not had this same issue in the past. So maybe something changed with an update? Actually all my colleagues (6 other mac and windows computers) have the exact same problem.

*R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)

Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

ggplot2: 2.2.1

knitr: 1.15.1*

Comment: Try it with `stat="count"` if you want ggplot to aggregate it for you.  `stat="identity"` plots the numbers in the file without aggregating, so is just stacking lots of short bars.

Comment: @Andrew, I think they're sums, not counts. `ggplot(mpg, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hwy)) + stat_summary(fun.y = 'sum', geom = 'bar')` should work.

Comment: @Axeman - Sorry, yes, I agree.

Comment: Thanks a lot AndrewGustar and @Axeman, yes *stat_summary* is working. But any idea why there is a difference between the plot in R-Studio and in the generated pdf when using the standard geom_bar? Is that intentionally?

Comment: @Nino, one difference is that (I think) RStudio renders the plot as raster graphics while the pdf has vector graphics. That said, I don't believe the pdf output is as originally intended.

Comment: You are right. If I save my original plot with `ggsave("MyPlot.pdf")` or `svg`  I get the stripes. This does not happen for instance with `png` or `wmf`. So there must still be a little bug in either of the formats (whether it is planed to have the stripes or not).

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment, the file type for the graphic can influence the way the graphic renders in the output pdf.

Using the provided chunk:

````
```{r, echo = F, fig.cap = "My plot"}
ggplot(mpg) + geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hwy), stat="identity")
```
````

The default `dev` is pdf and the resulting graphic in the pdf is as shown in the question post:

[image]

If you are explicit on the `dev` to use, as in the chunk below, then a png will be generated and the image in the resulting pdf is as wanted.

````
```{r, echo = F, fig.cap = "My plot", dev = "png"}
ggplot(mpg) + geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hwy), stat="identity")
```
````

[image]